# Issue when navigate inside a ListView

Tags: android, listview, react-native

I a a newbie on RN and i'm looking for a way to solve this issue. I found many informations on the Net but it still not working.

Here is my initial code :

```
import { StackNavigator, NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';
...
```

My function to populate the listitem from the datasource :

```
list(rowData, sectionID, rowID) {
  var onPress = () => this.props.navigation.goBack();
  return (
    <ListItem thumbnail onPress={onPress}>
      <Body>
        <Text>{rowData.Title}</Text>
        <Text numberOfLines={2}>
          <Icon name="map-marker" size={15} color="grey" />
          {rowData.Address}, {rowData.City} ({rowData.Distance} km)
        </Text>
        <Text numberOfLines={3}>{rowData.Description}</Text>
      </Body>
      {VerifiedUser}
    </ListItem>
  );
}
```

The onPress action send me error message :

> undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   '_this2.props.navigation.goBack()'

```
 render() {        
   return(    
     <Container> 
       <View style={styles.fill}>
         <ScrollView style={styles.fill}>
           <View style={styles.scrollViewContent}>
             <ListView
               dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
               renderRow={this.list.bind(this)} 
               enableEmptySections={true}
             />    
           </View>    
         </ScrollView>
       </View>
     </Container>
   );
 }
```

It seems like the componment is not recongnized.
Any help to make a sense to this error ?

Thank you!

Comment: is the `list` function defined within the component where it is used?

Comment: Oups, yes sorry. Yes it is.. I'm updating the code

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are using a `ListView` and `list` is the function for `renderRow` function. Your error caused by `this` not being bind. You can read about it more on [React Documentation for Handling Events](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html).

You need to bind your function to use `this` in it. You have couple of options.

First option is to bind it inline,

```
<ListView renderRow={this.list.bind(this)} />
```

Second option is binding in constructor,

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.list = this.list.bind(this);
  }

  list(rowData, sectionID, rowID) {
    // ...
  }

  render() {
    return(<ListView renderRow={this.list} />)
  }
}
```

Third option is using arrow functions,

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
  list = (rowData, sectionID, rowID) => {
    // ...
  }

  render() {
    return(<ListView renderRow={this.list} />)
  }
}
```

Comment: As you can see, i've already answer to yourcomment. The issue is not related to the "bind" but how to pass the navigate Component into the RenderRow

Comment: @MehmetAitAddi when I answered your question there were no part for how you used list function

Comment: Oh sorry, i thought it was updated before you make your suggestion :) sorry for that dude

Comment: Any help for this issue ?

Comment: @MehmetAitAddi can you add your navigation structure and where do you add this component that contains this ListView please